# XML Combo boxes cross binding with each other

Tags: xml, combobox, binding

Dears,

I am entering the XML world by customizing an UI for the Autodesk DataStandard add-in.

A **Combobox1** should be populated with items ***StandardTextInfo*** listed in an XML file. Each item is made of the following properties:
-StandardTextNumber
-StandardTextDE
-StandardTextEN
-StandardTextFR

Here is the *StandardText.XML* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StandardTextData xmlns="">
  <StandardTextInfo StandardTextNumber="10" DE="KATZE" EN="CAT" FR="CHAT"></StandardTextInfo>
  <StandardTextInfo StandardTextNumber="20" DE="HUND" EN="DOG" FR="CHIEN"></StandardTextInfo>
  <StandardTextInfo StandardTextNumber="30" DE="PFERD" EN="HORSE" FR="CHEVAL"></StandardTextInfo>
</StandardTextData>
```

A **Combobox2** should be populated with items ***LanguageInfo*** listed in an XML file. Each item is made of the property LanguageName (DE=Deutsch, EN=English, FR=Francais). Here is the *Language.XML* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LanguageData xmlns="">
  <LanguageInfo LanguageName="DE"></LanguageInfo>
  <LanguageInfo LanguageName="EN"></LanguageInfo>
  <LanguageInfo LanguageName="FR"></LanguageInfo>
</LanguageData>
```

Here is the intended usage:
-The User selects from **Combobox2** the language that the items will be displayed in into **Combobox1**.
-The values displayed in **Combobox1** *DisplayMemberPath* must be bound to the items property corresponding to the value selected in **Combobox2**. Items name can thus be displayed in the language chosen by the User.
-Beside, a **Combobox3** displays the property ***StandardTextNumber*** of the item selected in **Combobox1**. By using a Combobox (I talk about Combobox3) rather than a Label, the User has also the alternative to directly select the item property ***StandardTextNumber***, which reversely updates the item displayed in **Combobox1** (still in the language defined in **Combobox2**).

Here is the definition of the 3 comboboxes into the XAML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <WPF:MainWindow>
        x:Name="FileWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:WPF="clr-namespace:CreateObject.WPF;assembly=CreateObject"

    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider>
            x:Key="Languages"
            Source="C:\Language.xml"
            XPath="/LanguageData"
        </XmlDataProvider>
        <XmlDataProvider
            x:Key="StandardTexts"
            Source="C:\StandardText.xml"
            XPath="/StandardTextData"
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ComboBox>
        x:Name="Combobox1"
        IsEnabled="{Binding CreateMode}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StandardTexts}, XPath="StandardTextInfo"}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ComboBox3, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=ComboBox2, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectedValuePath="@StandardTextNumber"
        DisplayMemberPath="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=ComboBox3, Mode=OneWay}"
    </ComboBox>

    <ComboBox>
        x:Name="Combobox2"
        IsEnabled="{Binding CreateMode}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Languages}, XPath="LanguageInfo"}"
        SelectedValue="{Binding Prop[LanguageName].value}"
        SelectedValuePath="@LanguageName"
        DisplayMemberPath="@LanguageName"
    </ComboBox>

    <ComboBox>
        x:Name="Combobox3"
        IsEnabled="{Binding CreateMode}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StandardTexts}, XPath="StandardTextInfo"}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ComboBox1, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=ComboBox2, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectedValuePath="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=ComboBox1, Mode=OneWay}"
        DisplayMemberPath="@StandardTextNumber"
    </ComboBox>

    </WPF:MainWindow>
```

My questions:
1) **Combobox1** *SelectedValue* & *DisplayMemberPath*, **Combobox3** *SelectedValue* & *SelectedValuePath*: I probably miss the logic: how should be expressed the desired bindings?

2) In XML, what is the purpose of the prefix @ at forehead of bound properties?

3) I am pretty sure there is no really need for the source *Language.XML*: is it possible to populate **Combobox2** directly from the languages identified within the source *StandardText.XML*?

4) In which situation should the IsEnabled property be set to CreateMode or EditMode?

Thank you in advance for the kind advices you may provide.

Best regards,
Leon

Comment: Hello, is my request too easy or too hard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to question 1:

*StandardText.XML* and *Language.XML* files are not modified (see description in the above post)

Modification of the **3 comboboxes** into *File.XAML* or *Inventor.XAML* files (sorry I cannot highlight the modifications):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WPF:MainWindow>
    x:Name="FileWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WPF="clr-namespace:CreateObject.WPF;assembly=CreateObject"

<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider>
        x:Key="Languages"
        Source="C:\Language.xml"
        XPath="/LanguageData"
    </XmlDataProvider>
    <XmlDataProvider
        x:Key="StandardTexts"
        Source="C:\StandardText.xml"
        XPath="/StandardTextData"
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

<ComboBox>
    x:Name="Combobox1"
    IsEnabled="{Binding CreateMode}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StandardTexts}, XPath="StandardTextInfo"}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ComboBox3, Mode=OneWay}"
    # SelectedValue: no need to be defined
    # SelectedValuePath: no need to be defined
    DisplayMemberPath="{Binding ElementName=Combobox2, StringFormat=@{0}, Path=SelectedValue}"
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox>
    x:Name="Combobox2"
    IsEnabled="{Binding CreateMode}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Languages}, XPath="LanguageInfo"}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Prop[LanguageName].value}"
    SelectedValuePath="@LanguageName"
    DisplayMemberPath="@LanguageName"
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox>
    x:Name="Combobox3"
    IsEnabled="{Binding CreateMode}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StandardTexts}, XPath="StandardTextInfo"}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ComboBox1, Mode=OneWay}"
    # SelectedValue: no need to be defined
    SelectedValuePath="@StandardTextNumber"
    DisplayMemberPath="@StandardTextNumber"
</ComboBox>

</WPF:MainWindow>
```

Finally not so much modifications to get the expected result. The main points were:

-understand the purpose of *SelectedValue* and *SelectedValuePath* attributes

-the binding syntax StringFormat=@{0}

Questions 2 to 4 are now meaningless.

Many thanks to BAI Xuesong of BEIJING RNL SOFTWARE SCIENCE & TECH CO.LTD who provided the solution!

Best regards.